# Facebook cookie issue in IE9 and Chrome and FacebookWebClient initialization

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am playing with Facebook C# SDK to use with ASP>NET application, and was using FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized method after login on client side with JavaScript SDk to procceed with further actions (retrieve user info, friends list,etc). It was working on beginning but suddenly stop about week ago. FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized method is always false now. Checking further found that its working in Safari and Firefox 4, but fails in IE9 and Chrome.

It seems that IE9 doens't see facebook cookie like fbs_ApplicationID. Testing different examples in JavaSDk console on Facebook site shows that Facebook  FB.Cookie.load method doesn't return any value in IE9 and Chrome.

So my question, is there other way to "auhtorize" application on a server side using SDk? Is that Facebook side issue specific to browsers? FB.login callback function does return session info, but how I can use it then on server side to activate FacebookWebClient?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, but the behavior is very odd. It was working yesterday and now not working in Chrome and IE9. The fbWebContext.AccessToken is null and there's no fbs_xxxxx cookie. It's fine in Firefox and Safari.

Here's my code:

```
        var fbWebContext = FacebookWebContext.Current;
        var app = new FacebookWebClient(fbWebContext);
        dynamic fbUser = app.Get("me");
```

Comment: Somehow it started working in my case, quite not sure why. May be its not related
but in my application settings on Facebook side I use to have Site Domain field, which I cleared up and left blank. About same time my app started working in IE9 and Chrome.

Comment: I can confimrm this. I'm using the python SDK, and with Site Domain field set, I have problems reading the cookie with Chrome and IE. FireFox works OK. Clearing up the field has Chrome and IE working again.